# http:// Becomes http%3A%2F%2F in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The following redirect url becomes with http%3A%2F%2F instead of http://. How can I avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

```
$params = array(
            'client_id' => $client_id,
            'redirect_uri' => site_url('welcome/google_connect_redirect/'), 
            'state' => $_SESSION['state'],
            'approval_prompt' => 'force',
            'scope' => 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
            'response_type' => 'code'
        );
        $url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?".http_build_query($params);
        // send to google
        redirect($url);
```

URL becomes like this.

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=871111192098.apps.
googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8888%2Fmyappname
%2Findex.php%2Fwelcome%2Fgoogle_connect_redirect&state=f0babsomeletterscb5b48753358c
3b9&approval_prompt=force&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2F
userinfo.profile+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&
response_type=code
```

Comment: I don't think that will affect the redirection of the url.

Answer (score 3):

When you put strings with special characters into URL, they will be encoded, you can use `urldecode`

Answer (score 1):

The point of `http_build_query()` is that it `urlencode()`s each of the array's values for you before joining them in a querystring format. This is the preferred behavior.

Comment: Exactly.  It's actually a good thing that it's doing this.  OP, have you tested it out?  Is there a problem?

Answer (score 1):

The query string is encoded because there are some special characters that have special meaning in a URL.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#URL_encoding):

> Some characters cannot be part of a URL (for example, the space) and
>   some other characters have a special meaning in a URL: for example,
>   the character # can be used to further specify a subsection (or
>   fragment) of a document; the character = is used to separate a name
>   from a value. A query string may need to be converted to satisfy these
>   constraints. This can be done using a schema known as URL encoding.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually desired behavior and proper way to do it.

Look at manual and description of function [http_build_query](http://php.net/http_build_query)

> Generates a URL-encoded query string from the associative (or indexed) array provided.

So basically what it does it goes through whole array and urlencode it (that's why you see these characters) and joins it with &. If you want to avoid it then don't use http_build_query() but I really don't recommend it.